# Quitar borde de celdas excel

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una aplicación de consola que lee un excel protegido y lo vuelca en una base de datos, el problema surge que dicho excel tiene marcado los bordes de las celdas en todas las lineas.

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(item);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[2];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dichas celdas las lee como si fueran dato.

Como puedo evitar que lea los bordes como dato de dicho excel, el archivo excel no lo puedo editar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, en `xlRange`, puedes guardar el rango a leer que solo contenga datos, igual cuando haces un ctrl+fin para ubicar la última fila con datos. En el siguiente código, podrás almacenar dicho dato y recorrer el Excel hasta la última fila con datos:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(item);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[2];

int fin = xlWorksheet.Rows.Count;
int ultima = xlWorksheet.Cells[fin,1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.Range["A1", "última columna a leer" + ultima];
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: Gracias eduardo, pero desconozco cual puede ser la ultima linea con dato, la imagen de arriba es a modo de ejemplo puede tener 100 lineas en dato pero el bloque dibujado hasta la 1000, tomando como dato 1000 lineas

Comment: Estimado, creo que no se entendió lo que redacte. Voy a editar la respuesta. El código que deje en ella, encuentra la última fila y la almacena en xlRange, con este dato ha puedes recorrer el Excel hasta la última fila con dato

Comment: Lo pruebo eduardo y te comento